# updating list in qt creator

Tags: c++, linux, qt

hi every one i am working on qt creator. i have a list which is loaded with values store in a file when i run the program. but my problem is that the file is updating continuously after 30 sec so i want to refresh my list again with new values after 30 sec. how can i do that as sleep function is not working

i want that after running my program my list get updated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example:

```
QTimer *reloadTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(reloadTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(reloadTheList()));
reloadTimer->start(30000);
```

given a member function `this.reloadTheList()`, this code (eg. when run in constructor) tells the QTimer to `emit timeout()` every 30 seconds (30k miliseconds), which you connected to `signal reloadTheList()`

Comment: thank u sir but kindly tell me sir what is timer in the code timer->start(30000)

Comment: oops sorry, i copied it from one of my projects, forgot to rename, it has to be your QTimer instance (reloadTimer). EDIT: you can use as many QTimers you want, just connect their timeout() signals to the slot you want to call every X miliseconds, and call start(X) on them.
(of course you'll need several instances of QTimer, like *reloadTimer above)

Comment: anyway i would also sugesst reading the QT docs (QT Creator has a "Help" tab, but they are also [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/)). for information on qt objects just go to doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/OBJECT.html (where OBJECT.html is eg qtimer.html for QTimer, very intuitive names) or simply look at the index page.

Comment: thanks a lot sir thanks. you have solved my problem thanks u are awesome